# Can I use the eigenvectors values as columns weight for a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

The output of PCA are the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance (or correlation) matrix of the original data. Let's say the are `$x_1,...,x_n$` columns, then, there are `$z_1,...,z_n$` eigenvalues and `$\tilde{z_1},...,\tilde{z_n}$` eigenvectors. My question are:

- can I use the value `$\tilde{z_1}^{(1)},...,\tilde{z_1}^{(n)}$` of the first (or also the other) eigenvector as weight of my model? for example as the weight of the columns `$x_1,...,x_n$`, a kind of Unsupervised method.
- I understand the weight `$\tilde{z_1}^{(1)},...,\tilde{z_1}^{(n)}$` as the contribution value of every column. Is it correct?
- Can I use Spearman or Kendall correlation instead of covariance? Is it going to change the results?

I know that is it not a conventional way to use PCA but I would like to know if it makes sense.

Comment: ok, but I cannot really figure out, what this weight means. For example if I use kendall correlation, what the weight   $\phi^{(1)}_1,...,\phi^{(n)}_1$ means?if the weight of an element is bigger the respective column is more important? and if I take  $\phi^{(1)}_n,...,\phi^{(n)}_n$ the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue, what it is represent?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do whatever you want my friend. It's your model and you can use it in the way you want.

However, I wouldn't do that. PCA is a way to reduce dimensionality, you lose data to train your model faster. PCA can be seen as if you reduce a sphere of 3 dimensions to a circle of 2 dimensions. In some situations it can be useful.

With the output of PCA you can train your model and see what you get. However, have you tried to train your model without PCA? Maybe you don't need it and you are losing information that would improve your model

Comment: Yes, I have tried but I obtain slightly worst results, and for sure using a PCA formulation is more elegant.

Comment: Mmm maybe if you tell us what is the problem I could think of something.

Comment: I'm trying to combine different ranking using Borda count. In particular a weighted version where different ranking has different importance. To model this is enough multiply every ranking to its importance. For instance an array $W=[w_1,..,w_n]$ where $w_i$ represents the weight of the ranking $i$ (the weight means that a multiply the score of the column by the weight $w_i$). What I tried is run PCA and use the eigenvector values of the first component as weight.

Comment: One question, your final rank is a linear combination of weighted ranks? So the final rank has this shape: `R = w1*r1 + w2*r2 +...wn*rn`???

Comment: not exactly but yes. $w_i$ doesn't multiply the value r1 but multiply the score of the column r1, that is slightly different. (the score is calculated using the borda score https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count )

Comment: Ok, so your problem is `r1=w11*s11+w12*s12+...+w1n*s1n` until `rn=wn1*sn1+....+wnn*snn` I would try to use methods like linear regression, logistic regression or linear SVM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99114/discussion-between-andrea-madotto-and-hoap-humanoid).